# Linear gradients not working in Firefox 4

Tags: firefox, css, linear-gradients

I recently tried applying a gradient background to a webpage using only CSS3.
while testing out the following code:

```
body {background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, white);}
```

The result was:
[image: firefox grads went wrong]

Not exactly what I was looking for...
Any idea what is going on?
OS is Win7 64bit and Firefox 4.
Thanks!

Comment: The first example in this [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/using_gradients)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may want to add `no-repeat` to that background property…

or set a height to the `<body>` (and the `<html>`) like so:

```
html { height: 100%; }
body { background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, blue, white); height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess firefox have problem in setting gradients for elements without declared width....

Comment: @GZaidman it's not a problem with Firefox, it's doing exactly what it's supposed to do given what you told it.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because the height of the body is small, and by default the background is repeating.

You can either make it not repeat:

```
body { background-repeat: no-repeat; }
```

or make the height of the container (`html`) the size of the window:

```
html { height: 100%; }
```

though note that the latter can sometimes have unexpected effects when scrolling.